# Permission Denied inside a Cron script

Tags: permissions, cron, selinux

I am having issues with commands (ls and find) not working inside a script when run via crontab.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

whoami
ls -l /
ls -l /u01
```

The results:

```
+ whoami
oracle
+ ls -l /
total 640
-rw-r--r--.    1   root root
...Rest left out for brevity.
+ ls -l /u01
ls: cannot open directory /u01: Permission denied
```

This same script runs fine interactively.

The permissions for /u01 are:

```
drwxr-xr-x.    8  oracle oinstall       4096   Mar 17    2021 u01
```

I have tried sourcing profile files.  I have provided the full path to the ls command.  I can ls other directories without issue.  Searching the WWW, has not given me many clues to fix this issue.

Comment: It seems as if the script you show is not the script from which you show the output (note the options used with `ls`). Make sure that you are running the script that you believe you are running.  Also, it would be helpful to see the permissions on the `/u01` directory in the output from the cron job.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I am trying to fix this issue and grabbed the other script that I am also trying, which by the way does not work either.  The output shows the same permissions on the /u01 directory drwxr-xr-x.

Comment: Are "_the results_" the results of running the script interactively or via crontab?

Comment: Is `/u01` a network filesystem or a local one?

Comment: If you replace `whoami` with `id` do you get an expected result?

Comment: Interestingly, when I compare with the uid and gid between the cron job and interactively, they are the same.  The difference lies in the context,

At the command prompt:
```
id -Z
system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0,c1023
```
In the crontab the output is:
```
user_u:user_r:user_t:s0
```
It looks like selinux is causing this issue.